# get current date and use Junit to assert against a specific format to check they match

Tags: java, date, selenium, junit, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver to get the current displayed date from my webpage, which shows in the format:

Friday 13th December

I then want to use a Junit assertEquals to check it is displaying today's date.

So I need to fetch the current date with Java and then convert to this format to do the comparison. I think I need to use SimpleDateFormat class then use the E d M pattern.

I'm not clear on the syntax, something like:

```
WebElement currentDate = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".currentDate"));
    assertEquals("expected match on text", Calendar.getInstance()(some code here to convert to E d M) , currentDate.getText());
```

EDIT: Thanks Yuvaraj. So, the following works:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE d MMMM");
    String strTodaysDate = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
    strTodaysDate = strTodaysDate.substring(0,9) + "th" + strTodaysDate.substring(9,18);
    System.out.println(strTodaysDate);
```

...and prints "Friday 13th December".  The only problem I have now is concatenating the ordinal "th" in the correct position when the days change and the char positions move?

Comment: `E d M` won't include the ordinal part ("th"). I'd strongly suggest building up the expected value separately, rather than trying to do it in one expression. You'll want to use `SimpleDateFormat` to do the formatting, too. (Or Joda Time...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Code is to get the current date in String format. Choose the format you want and compare it with the `currentDate.getText();`

```
Date cur_dt = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM");
String strTodaysDate = dateFormat.format(cur_dt);
```

Comment: I suggest you fetch the day from currentDate.getText(); and reconstruct it to make it someting like Friday 13 December and then do the compare.

Comment: Code to get the day:   String day  = currentDate.getText().replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1");

Comment: your date in app may contain "1st" or "2nd" or "3rd"  so better not hardcode with "th".

Comment: Good point. I'd probably be best to ignore the ordinal value when doing the assertion though I'm not sure how this is done.

Comment: String day  = currentDate.getText().replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1");

String splitDate[] =  currentDate.getText().split(" ");

String modifiedDateInApp = splitDate[0] + " " + day +  " " +  splitDate[2]

Now compare  modifiedDateInApp  and  strTodaysDate